# Showing results of subtractions using Two-Way Data binding

Tags: java, android, android-layout, two-way-binding

Is it possible to subtract the values of two EditTexts together, and displaying their result in a TextView using two-way data binding?

Comment: Whenever text changes in edittext, calculate the result and post the value in livedata, and observe the livedata in textview in layout.

Comment: @Muneesh Ok. That makes sense. I was over complicating things, thank you.